# How to create pdf from a panel in window app using winnovative

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, pdf, winnovative

Is it possible to create a pdf from a panel in a windows app using winnovative HTML to PDF converter? I see that it works if using a WebBrowser contr, however i have data grids in a panel that need to be pdf'd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can see it in your WebBrowser control is that it relies on IE's context menu handling. Winnovative's software injects a context menu entry into IE so that you can quickly produce a PDF. This won't work for your DataGridView, but you could perform a workaround by producing a table in HTML and writing it to a temporary WebBrowser control.

Comment: @Polynominal Sounds logical I'll try that.